# Macro to paste values in the blank column for a particular row

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different files say 'File_A' & 'File_B'. I have copied the data from 'File_A', now I want to paste it in 'File_B'
How do I paste it in the last blank column for a particular row..(say 102 row no)

Below is my code..but my data gets pasted in the previous column everytime I run it..say first time it gets pasted in column D, then in column C like that.

Please suggest the changes in my code.

```
    Sub Test()
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Data\File_B"
    Worksheets("Sheet9").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet9").Select
    
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("File_B").Sheets("A1").Activate
    Dim last_col As Integer
    
    last_col = Cells(102, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select
    
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: When you say `last blank column`, do you mean the first blank column after your data? Your `last_col` actually selects the last column with data, not the blank column. You are overwriting the data in the last used column each time your run your code. You need to `Offset` the `last_col` variable, 1 column to the right.  Also, you should look up how not to use `Activate` and `Select`

Comment: Thanks @GMalc..Offset worked..I will check how to avoid using Activate and Select as per your suggestion